# mysql Get A positive & negative result from sum()

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

I have mysql table with structure as:

```
`credit` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`debit` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
```

And i want to get sum result as positive & negative, just like:
[look at data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEFrQ.png) here

when i run this

```
sum(credit - debit) as total
```

results always return positive value even that Negative

i want results to be positive if it positive and negative if it negative

positive : -123

negative : 123

how can i do that ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Positive and negative from which column, and under which conditions? Sample data, desired resuts, and a better explanation would all help clarifying your question.

Comment: sorry , i've updated my question now

Comment: So you want the same result in both columns, one positive and the other negative?

Comment: when i run this

sum(credit - debit) as total 
results always return positive value even that Negative

i want results to be positive if it positive and negative if it negative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you want:

```
select
    sum(credit - debit) total,
    abs(sum(credit - debit)) total_as_positive,
    - abs(sum(credit - debit) total_as_negative
from mytable
```

Or, if you want to put the result in a different column depending on its sign:

```
select
    case when sum(credit - debit) > 0 then sum(credit - debit) end positive,
    case when sum(credit - debit) < 0 then sum(credit - debit) end negative
from mytable
```